# Creating acrobat links in source document

Tags: acrobat

I've used Acrobat Pro for many years but only scraped the surface of its capabilities.

Here's the problem I'm facing, I'm sure that Acrobat can deal with it, I just can't figure out how...

So... I have a wiki based content management system from which I need to regularly produce packs of content (consisting of up to 250 articles), packaged as a single PDF.

I have the Webkit html - pdf conversion engine up and running and have written code (javascript/jquery) that selects the relevant articles (based on user input), sorts them alphabetically and PDFs them into a single acrobat document. The process creates simple bookmarks, one for each article, based on its title.

So far, so good...

I also dynamically create a second document that contains a Table of Contents and index.

An example... The wiki contains pages:

```
All about Foo  
All about Bar  
All about Baz
```

These are exported into a single PDF, in the order

```
All about Bar
All about Baz
All about Foo
```

And bookmarks are created that link to each 'page'

The ToC and index are then created as temp wiki pages (using Javascript and JQuery) and exported to PDF eg:

```
1 All about Bar
2 All about Baz
3 All about Foo
```

And

```
Bar           1
Baz           2
Foo           3
Systems    1,2,3
Kittens      2,3
Etc etc
```

This has worked fine and everyone has been happy. However, in the nature of users everywhere, they want more. Specifically, they want to merge the ToC and Index into the PDF (that part's easy) and link on the article numbers.

That's where my knowledge and the results I can pull out of Google come to a halt. I can do it manually of course but with three or four of these packs per week, each containing between 20 and 350 articles and well over a thousand index entries - that would be a world of pain.

As the ToC and Index are generated by scripts, I can wrap the numbers in any sort of html markup.
I wondered about something like

```
 <a href="#All%20about%20Foo">4</a>
```

But don't see how to pick up on that on merge so that it converts the html links to pdf ones.

Any ideas or pointers?